# jQuery Fluid Videos - in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the script form this website.
https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

```
// Find all YouTube videos
var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

How can I take this jQuery script and modify with Wordpress?  I'm putting it inside of a script tag at the bottom of my page on a document ready.  In wordpress it says to use jQuery instead of $.  How do I call my variables then as well as define them?  Where does $fluidEl come from?

Comment: Replace `$`with `jQuery`and remove `$` from all your variables. In JS there is no need to use $ for variables.

Comment: This really helped me complete my script and get it working on Wordpress.  Thank You.